# Extract step pulse from 1D signal for object segmentation

Tags: python, vector, image-segmentation

I have 1D vector and i want to get the start and the end locations of the rectangle signal inside (highlighted in the images below). I am using python, and this signal is a histogram of white pixels inside a binary image on y-axis. I am trying to get the ROI of the object without the noise around it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a naive solution but it works. Starting fro the middle point, search for the sharp dropping in left and right.

```
def get_start_end(projection):
    middle_indx = int(len(projection)/2)
    middle_value = projection[middle_indx]
    print "middle index is = ", middle_indx, " it's value is ", middle_value
    #-- search for sharp dropping right (end)
    for i, v in enumerate(projection[middle_indx+1:]):
        diff = int(middle_value) - v
        if(diff > 0.5*middle_value):
            end = i + middle_indx+1
            break

    #-- search for sharp dropping left (start)
    for i, v in enumerate(projection[:middle_indx]):
        diff = int(middle_value) - v
        if(diff > 0.5*middle_value):
            start = i
    return start, end
```

--EDIT

In case we didn't found a drop higher than the `ratio*middle_value`, find the maximum drop instead.

```
def get_plate_y_coordinates(projection_vector):
    ratio = 0.5
    middle_indx = int(len(projection_vector)/2)
    middle_value = projection_vector[middle_indx]
    start = 0
    end = len(projection_vector)
    print "middle index is = ", middle_indx, " it's value is ", middle_value

    #-- search for sharp dropping right (end)
    saved_diff = []
    for i, v in enumerate(projection_vector[middle_indx+1:]):
        diff = int(middle_value) - v
        if(diff > ratio*middle_value):
            end = i + middle_indx+1
            break
        else:
            saved_diff.append((diff, i + middle_indx+1))

    if (end == len(projection_vector)) and (len(saved_diff)>0): #didn't chage
        saved_diff = np.array(saved_diff)
        sorted_diff = saved_diff[saved_diff[:,0].argsort()[::-1],:]
        end = int(sorted_diff[0,1])

    #-- search for sharp dropping left (start)
    saved_diff=[]
    for i, v in enumerate(projection_vector[:middle_indx]):
        diff = int(middle_value) - v
        if(diff > ratio*middle_value):
            start = i
        else:
            saved_diff.append((diff, i))

    if (start == 0) and (len(saved_diff)>0): #didn't chage
        saved_diff = np.array(saved_diff)
        sorted_diff = saved_diff[saved_diff[:,0].argsort()[::-1],:]
        start = int(sorted_diff[0,1])
    return start, end
```

[image]
[image]